# How to register a class that implements multiple interfaces in MVVM Light's SimpleIoc?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mvvm-light, ioc-container

Let's say I have a couple of interfaces and a class that implements them:

```
public interface ISomething1 { /* blablabla */ }
public interface ISomething2 { /* blablabla */ }
public class Service : ISomething1, ISomething2 { /* blablabla x 2 */ }
```

I'd like to register the class in the SimpleIoc with both of these interfaces:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISomething1, Service >();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISomething2, Service >();
```

However the second line here throws an **ArgumentException** with the message:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

I'd have thought that the key here is the interface itself, but apparently that's not the case. My idea was to use explicit keys however I'd like to get the instances via dependency injection, where the IoC can only work with keyless registries.

So how could I use SimpleIoc here without changing either of the interfaces or the implementation itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably this is a better solution because Service() constructor can have dependencies registered in the ioc container.

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Service>();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISomething1>(() => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Service>());
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISomething2>(() => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<Service>());
```

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the source code here ([SimpleIoc.cs on CodePlex](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20%28PCL%29/Ioc/SimpleIoc.cs)) has revealed what the problem was. When using this overload of the register function:

```
public void Register<TInterface, TClass>(bool createInstanceImmediately)
```

as anticipated it will add *TInterface* and *TClass* to a dictionary where the interface is the key, however it also adds *TClass* and its constructor to another dictionary where the class is the key without any further checks.

I suspect it is a bug as if TClass was already known (ie. added to this constructor lookup map) it could simply live with that.

---

### Solution:

The solution / workaround is to use the factory type of registration. This works as expected:

```
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISomething1>(() => new Service());
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ISomething2>(() => new Service());
```

Comment: Note that with this solution, a new instance of the class will be created everytime you ask one of the two interfaces.